# Shrine + JQuery File Upload only uploading cache file to S3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload

Fairly new to rails and trying out Shrine and Jquery File Uploads to S3, I got the cache file to upload but the image never gets uploaded. I was following the GoRails videos on it but it seems like those are horribly outdated.

I have an Autos model which is supposed to accept images as one of the fields in the form, a Users model through devise and a user has many auto_posts

Uploads.js:

```
    $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function(){
   $("[type=file]").fileupload({
      add: function(e, data) {
          console.log("add", data);
          data.progressBar = $('<div class="progress"><div class="determinate" style="width: 70%"></div></div>').insertBefore("form")
          var options = {
              extension: data.files[0].name.match(/(\.\w+)?$/)[0], //set the file extention
             _: Date.now() //prevent caching
          };

          $.getJSON("/autos/upload/cache/presign", options, function(result) {
              console.log("presign", result);
              data.formData = result['fields'];
              data.url = result['url'];
              data.paramName = "file";
              data.submit()
          });

      },
      progress: function(e, data) {
      console.log("progress", data);
      var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
      var percentage = progress.toString() + '%'
      data.progressBar.find(".progress-bar").css("width", percentage).html(percentage);
      },
      done: function(e, data) {
      console.log("done", data);
      data.progressBar.remove();


      var image = {
        id: data.formData.key.match(/cache\/(.+)/)[1], // we have to remove the prefix part
        storage:  'cache',
        metadata: {
          size: data.files[0].size,
          filename: data.files[0].name.match(/[^\/\\]+$/)[0], // IE return full path
          mime_type: data.files[0].type
        }
      }
      form = $(this).closest("form");
      form_data = new FormData(form[0]);
      form_data.append($(this).attr("name"), JSON.stringify(image))

      $.ajax(form.attr("action"), {
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        method: form.attr("method"),
        dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log("done from rails", data);
            });
      }
   }); 
});
```

Shrine.rb

```
require "shrine/storage/s3"

s3_options = {
  access_key_id:     Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id,
  secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key,
  region:            Rails.application.secrets.aws_region,
  bucket:            Rails.application.secrets.aws_bucket,
}

Shrine.storages = {
  cache: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "cache",upload_options: {acl: "public-read"}, **s3_options),
  store: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "store",upload_options: {acl: "public-read"}, **s3_options),
}

Shrine.plugin :presign_endpoint
Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :direct_upload
Shrine.plugin :restore_cached_data
```

Autos controller:

```
class AutosController < ApplicationController
     before_action :find_auto, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
   def index
       @autos = Auto.all.order("created_at DESC")
   end

   def show

   end

    def new
        @auto = current_user.autos.build
    end

    def create
      @auto = current_user.autos.build(auto_params)

      if @auto.save
          flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post."
          redirect_to autos_path
      else
          render 'new'
      end
    end

    def edit
       end

    def update
         if @auto.update(auto_params)
             flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated post."
            redirect_to auto_path(@auto)
        else
            render 'edit'
    end
    end

    def destroy
    @auto.destroy
    redirect_to autos_path
    end
    private 
   def auto_params
    params.require(:auto).permit(:title, :price, :description, :contact, :image, :remove_image)
end

def find_auto
    @auto = Auto.find(params[:id])     
end
end
```

My Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #mount ImageUploader::UploadEndpoint => "/images/upload"
  mount Shrine.presign_endpoint(:cache) => "/autos/upload/cache/presign"
    devise_for :users
    resources :autos
    resources :jobs
    root 'index#index'

    get 'categories', to: 'index#categories'
    get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
    get 'getstarted', to: 'pages#getstarted'
end
```

The form is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-panel">
        <% if @auto.errors.any? %>
        <% @auto.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    Materialize.toast('<%= msg %>', 10000, 'red')
  </script>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>   

<%= simple_form_for @auto do |f| %>

  <%= f.file_field :image %>

<%= f.input :title, label: "Name of Vehicle" %>
<%= f.input :price, label: "Asking Price" %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<%= f.input :contact, label: "Contact Info" %>
<%= f.button :submit, class: "btn light-blue darken-3" %>
<%= link_to "Cancel", autos_path, class: "btn waves-effect waves-light red 
accent-4" %>
<% end %>

</div>
</div>
```

I'm sure it's just an easy tweak to the uploads.js file and the autos controller but I'm at a loss here as to what to do. I appreciate any help

Comment: The GoRails screencasts shouldn't be "horribly outdated", the only thing that changed is that `presign_endpoint` plugin replaced `direct_upload`. Can you post your `config/routes.rb` and the form? What do you mean with "the image never gets uploaded"? As I understood, the image does get uploaded to S3 on the client side, but it's failing to be attached to the record? Does the image JSON data get submitted to the Rails app?

Comment: I have added the code for the form and the routes.rb file. On choosing the image, a cache file appears in my S3 bucket, however on submission of the form the image never shows up in the S3 bucket. [This is the rails log on choosing an image](https://i.imgur.com/EmKNaW1.png)

Comment: The Rails log looks right, so it looks that the file data was submitted to the app correctly. I don't see what else could have gone wrong. If you enable Shrine logging with `Shrine.plugin :logging`, do you see the cached file get uploaded to permanent storage? Also, what is the content of `@auto.image` before and after `@auto.save`?

Comment: The cached file is uploaded to my S3 bucket no problem.I know it's a jquery problem because I got basic shrine to S3 uploads to work perfectly. How do I find out the content before and after?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the CORS settings on your bucket? 
[Here's how the official docs recommend setting it.](http://shrinerb.com/rdoc/files/doc/direct_s3_md.html#label-Enabling+CORS)

From the docs:

```
require "aws-sdk-s3"

client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  access_key_id:     "<YOUR KEY>",
  secret_access_key: "<YOUR SECRET>",
  region:            "<REGION>",
)

client.put_bucket_cors(
  bucket: "<YOUR BUCKET>",
  cors_configuration: {
    cors_rules: [{
      allowed_headers: ["Authorization", "Content-Type", "Origin"],
      allowed_methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      allowed_origins: ["*"],
      max_age_seconds: 3000,
    }]
  }
)
```